# I can't override a table in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in excel VBA

```
   'Create query table to hold the rates.
   With objBK.Worksheets(1)
      Set objQT = .QueryTables.Add( _
         Connection:="URL;https://xxx.output=XLS", _
         Destination:=.Range("A1"))
   End With
```

`https://xxx.output=XLS` return an XLS table that is written in A1 cell of my worksheet.

The problem is that every time I run this query it keeps adding the table in A1 shifting the previous table and NOT overriding it.

How can I override old table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep adding new ones when you actually want to adjust the existing one.  Give your QueryTable a name (objQT.Name = "blah").  Then when you need to adjust it, get hold of *that* QueryTable and make your adjustments to it.

Alternatively, just delete the old one before creating a new one.